# XP on new partition, can no longer boot windows 7 on main?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I created a new partition on my sata drive so i could install windows XP on it whilst having windows 7 on my main partition (C

i have installed XP on this new partition but now every time i boot the computer it automatically boots XP and it doesnt give me the option which operating system i want to boot. So i can't boot Windows 7 anymore

Can anyone help to allow my computer to choose which operating system i want on startup?

Answer (score 0):

With the Windows XP installation your Windows 7 boot loader in the MBR got overwritten by the one from XP. Therefore, only Windows XP will be booted right now.

To get a boot menu to choose the OS from, follow [this guide](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/8057-dual-boot-installation-windows-7-xp.html) (scroll down to *Option Two - When Windows 7 is Installed First*, Step 7).